# How to deploy a powershell-installer via the intune-portal?

Tags: command-line, powershell, installation, intune, scoop

I've got the powershell install script for the windows command-liner installer **Scoop** which is called: `install.ps1`. After downloading the script with

```
irm get.scoop.sh -outfile 'install.ps1'
```

I want to depoly it over the Intune-Portal. I am well aware that Intune got a section where you explicitly can deploy powershell scripts. I don't want to do it that way, because I want to learn/know how/if it's possible this way.

My question is, how the install-command for a powershell-script differs from the command used for an `msi` or an `exe`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some testing and researching I found out three things:

- intune uses the `cmd.exe`-syntax under the hood and not `powershell.exe`-syntax
- all commands are run in administrative mode
- the scoop-installer does not like elevated rights by default and needs therefore a certain option

With these things in mind I can give intune the right command for an **silent-install**.

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -File install.ps1 -RunAsAdmin
```

I am executing the powershell with different options which bypass the ExecutionPolicy (if not already set) and hides/silences/quiets the opening powershell console.

After the `-File` option I declare the script which shall execute and the scoop-installer-specific `-RunAsAdmin` option. It is important to put the `-File` option at the end of the command, because everything after it, gets interpreted as part of `install.ps1`.

For the sake of completeness, here is also the **silent-uninstall**-command:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -WindowStyle Hidden -NonInteractive -Command "del $HOME\scoop -Force -Recurse | Out-Null"
```

I know that the task of the uninstall-command, could also be achieved with pure `cmd`-syntax, but I wanted to stay close to the [documentation](https://github.com/ScoopInstaller/Scoop/wiki/Uninstalling-Scoop).